# Laravel cannot get duplicate value datas using join query

Tags: laravel

I using laravel 5.3 in my project.

I want to get result for duplicate value (i.e.,)If the column has same id it should be displayed.

```
public function getSendedRequests($broker_id) {
    $broker = User::where('broker_id', $broker_id)->lists('id');
    //my customer sended request
    $getUser = ProfileRequest::whereIn('requested_id', $broker)->lists('requested_id');
    $getReq = ProfileRequest::whereIn('requested_id', $broker)->lists('user_id');
    $sendUsers = $this->commonRequestQuery($getUser);
    $receivedUsers = $this->commonRequestQuery($getReq);
    return view('profilerequest')->with(['sendUsers' => $sendUsers->paginate(10), 'receivedUsers' => $receivedUsers->get(), 'title' => trans('messages.customer-sended-requests')]);
}

public function commonRequestQuery($values) {
    return DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('basic_informations', 'users.id', '=', 'basic_informations.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('physical_attributes', 'users.id', '=', 'physical_attributes.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('religion_and_ethnicity', 'users.id', '=', 'religion_and_ethnicity.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('occupational_attributes', 'users.id', '=', 'occupational_attributes.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('personal_interests', 'users.id', '=', 'personal_interests.user_id')
        ->select('users.id', 'users.user_name', 'users.email', 'users.gender', 'basic_informations.age', 'basic_informations.unique_id', 'basic_informations.mother_tongue', 'religion_and_ethnicity.religion_id', 'religion_and_ethnicity.caste_id', 'occupational_attributes.education_id', 'occupational_attributes.occupation_id')
        ->whereNotNull('basic_informations.user_id')
        ->whereNotNull('physical_attributes.user_id')
        ->whereNotNull('religion_and_ethnicity.user_id')
        ->whereNotNull('occupational_attributes.user_id')
        ->whereIn('users.id', $values);
}
```

I get users id from user table for same broker and check whether they have requested some one in another table.

My problem is if the same user requested for two another users then i cannnot get result twice instead of that i can get only one time but another users(request received users is displayed propery).

Profile request table looks like image
[image]

In requested_id table im having same id two times i want to display parallely like **Who requested for whom**

Comment: request received users is displayed propery because no duplicate user (see in image) otherwise same issue occurred. so, you need to join  profileRequest pivot table with user table and group by profileRequest.id. try this

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor Yes its displaying properly i think the problem is with join query